# Python module location

Tags: python, math, module, location

I have been trying to find the location of a module but can't I have searched the python folder but still can't find it but I know it's there

```
>>> import math
>>> math.__path__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <module>
    math.__path__
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__path__'
>>> math.__file__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#14>", line 1, in <module>
    math.__file__
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__file__'
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I fixed the formatting for you by highlighting the code and hitting the code [`{}`] button.

Comment: I think math is a builtin module.

Comment: It completely depends on your install.

Comment: Thank you, how did you do that? hitting the code button only told me to quadruple space to start a code block :/ maybe I just missed something, next question I post I'll look at it.

Comment: Telling him "it's builtin" doesn't tell him where it is... it must be somewhere, even if it's in something like `libpython.so`.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I meant built into the executable. And right, as Ignacio said; I just checked on my Mac and math lives in a shared library object. Upvote for Ignacio.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it has no `__file__` attribute then that means that it's probably built into the Python library itself (or some other executable), and does not exist independently on disk.

Comment: ah ok thank you, Do you know of some python module (installed by default) that I could look at for a module example?

Comment: `site` is usually a separate file.